# Python - Identifying/Processing an Image

Tags: python, image-processing, detection, image

I'm looking in to learning about processing and handling images with Python. I'm experimenting with searching the inside of an image for a specific picture. For example, this picture has two images in it that are the same;

[image]

In Python, how would I go about detecting which two images are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at [OpenCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20130815032721/http://opencv.willowgarage.com:80/wiki) and [PIL](https://python-pillow.org/), if you want to implement simple (or complex) algorithms on your own.
Furthermore you can integrate OpenCV with PIL and also [numpy](https://numpy.org/), which makes it a really powerful tool for this kind of jobs.